# How to stop the Metronic wizard if validation fails

Tags: angular, metronic

It is navigating to the next step even on error. Below is my code.Please help

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    // Initialize form wizard
    const wizard = new KTWizard(this.el.nativeElement, {
        startStep: 1
    });

    // Validation before going to next page
    wizard.on('beforeNext', function (wizardObj) {

        // validate the form and use below function to stop the wizard's step
        const form = this.addLocationForm as FormGroup;
        if(!form.valid) {
            wizardObj.stop();
            console.log(form.errors);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

There is another way

```
// Validation before going to next page
wizard.on("beforeNext", wizardObj => {
  if (wizardObj.currentStep === 1) {
    if (this.form.invalid) {
      this.form.markAllAsTouched();
      wizardObj.stop();
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably to late, but this should work :

```
function (wizardObj) {
    step = wizardObj.getStep();
    const form = this.addLocationForm as FormGroup;
    if(!form.valid) {
        wizardObj.goTo(step);
    }
});
```

Retrieve current step :

```
step = wizardObj.getStep();
```

Go to specific step :

```
wizardObj.goTo(step);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know, I might be too late for this answer but I found the following solution in some other thread or in docs.
Metronic Author/developers have changed the wizard operation in its latest version, From:

```
this.wizard.on('beforeNext', (wizardObj) => {
   //your code
});
```

To:

```
this.wizard.on('change', (wizardObj) => {
//your code
});
```